# Can I call assignment operator of its base class without writing operator=()?

Tags: c++

I have a template class. The template parameter is set as a base class of the template class; Please see the following code. Can I call assignment operator=() of base class without writing operator=()? I hope you can get what I want to tell you reading and comparing the following lines,

```
this->template T_Base::operator=(orig);  // This is ok
```

and

```
this->template T_Base = orig;  // Error
```

. I would like to know the way of writing the second one.
Thank you very much.

```
class Base {
public:
    Base& operator= (const Base& orig) {
        return *this;
    }
    virtual ~Base() {};
};

template <typename T_Base>
class TemplateBase : public T_Base {
public:
    TemplateBase& operator= (const TemplateBase& orig) {
        this->template T_Base::operator=(orig);  // This is ok
        this->template T_Base = orig;  // Error
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: Static cast? `static_cast<T_Base&>(*this) = orig;`

Comment: Thank you Vaughn Cato. It works.

Comment: `T_Base::operator=(orig);`. And that `template` is completely wrong.